# WebAPI FAIL on Azure Computer Emulator

Tags: c#, azure, azure-compute-emulator

I'm using Azure SDK 2.1, when I start the azure Compute emulator I got the following problem

[image]

when I open WaIISHost.log I get the following

[image]

ServiceDefinition.csdef:
[image]

******UPDATE 2013-10-28 12:50******

When I use the **FULL Emulator** everything works.

Comment: Show your `ServiceDefinition.csdef`

Comment: How are you equating an unauthorized access exception with the emulator failing? Your question title is misleading, as it sounds like the emulator itself is failing (and that's not shown in the exception you pasted into your question).

Comment: @DavidMakogon it was working normally in the last 2 days, just today without any modification this problem happen.

Comment: Try to comment your [Authorize] filters (in case you are using) and run it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open visual studio as **administrator**; and run your cloud service using the **FULL Emulator**.
- When everything works normally, restart the visual studio with your normal user.
- now run your visual studio as a **normal user**; and run your cloud service using the **Emulator Express**.
- Everything should work normally now.